# Error with CMD ["gunicorn", "foodgram.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0:8000"] comand

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose on Windows 10 19044.1766 to run containers.
backend container keeps restarting with error:

> standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format
> error

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
COPY . /app
CMD ["gunicorn", "foodgram.wsgi:application", "--bind,", "0:8000"]
```

I have tried:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
FROM python:3.8-slim
```

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "foodgram.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0:8000"] 
CMD gunicorn foodgram.wsgi:application --bind 0:8000 
CMD ["gunicorn", "foodgram.wsgi:application", "--bind" 
 "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Same error

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
    version: '3.3'
    
    volumes:
      postgres_data:
      static:
      media:
      static_value:
      media_value:
      frontend_data:
    
    services:
      db:
        image: postgres:12.4
        volumes:
          - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        env_file:
          - ../backend/.env
      
      backend:
        image: mastermind777nest/foodgram:latest
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - static_value:/app/static/
          - media_value:/app/media/
        depends_on:
          - db
        env_file:
          - ../backend/.env
    
      frontend:
        build:
          context: ../frontend
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ../frontend/:/app/result_build/
    
      nginx:
        image: nginx:1.19.3
        ports:
          - "10080:80"
          - "10443:443"
        volumes:
          - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
          - ../frontend/build:/usr/share/nginx/html/
          - ../docs/:/usr/share/nginx/html/api/docs/
          - static:/app/static/
          - media:/app/media/
          - static_value:/var/html/static/
          - media_value:/var/html/media/
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - backend
          - frontend
```

Structure

[image]

same error on remote server ubuntu Intel Ice Lake
sudo docker container ls:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                          PORTS                                                                                NAMES
f3f02eaf2a41   nginx:1.19.3                        "/docker-entrypoint.…"   7 minutes ago   Up 7 minutes                    0.0.0.0:10080->80/tcp, :::10080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10443->443/tcp, :::10443->443/tcp   nesterenok_nginx_1
7c03bf654bd0   mastermind777nest/foodgram:latest   "gunicorn foodgram.w…"   7 minutes ago   Restarting (3) 44 seconds ago                                                                                        nesterenok_backend_1
7b7b5aeaef71   postgres:12.4                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   25 hours ago    Up 7 minutes                    5432/tcp                                                                             nesterenok_db_1
```

workflow to deploy:

```
name: Foodgram

on: [push]

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install flake8 pep8-naming flake8-broken-line flake8-return flake8-isort
          pip install -r backend/requirements.txt
          
      - name: Test with flake8
        run: python -m flake8
          
          
  build_and_push_to_docker_hub:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: tests
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
        
      - name: Login to Docker
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
          
      - name: Push to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          context: ./backend/
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/foodgram:latest
          

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build_and_push_to_docker_hub
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    steps:
      - name: executing remote ssh commands to deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USER }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          stack_file_name: docker-compose.yaml
          script: |
            sudo docker pull ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/foodgram:latest
            sudo docker-compose stop
            sudo docker-compose rm backend
            sudo docker-compose up -d


  send_message:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      needs: deploy
      steps:
        - name: send message
          uses: appleboy/telegram-action@master
          with:
            to: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TO }}
            token: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
            message: ${{ github.workflow }} успешно выполнен!
```

requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.2
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==21.4.0
colorama==0.4.5
Django==4.0.5
django-filter==22.1
djangorestframework==3.13.1
flake8==4.0.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
isort==5.10.1
mccabe==0.6.1
packaging==21.3
pluggy==1.0.0
py==1.11.0
pycodestyle==2.8.0
pyflakes==2.4.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pytest==7.1.2
pytz==2022.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
tomli==2.0.1
tzdata==2022.1
```

Comment: You have a comma at the end of `"--bind,"` in your command, pretty sure that's not right and you probably want to use `0.0.0.0` instead of just `0` for the hostname

Comment: changed to CMD ["gunicorn", "foodgram.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
same error

Comment: Windows 10 19044.1766

Comment: Make sure gunicorn is in your requirements.txt file. Also, between testing with different CMDs, be sure to run `docker-compose build`.

Comment: For debugging what are the results if you set the base image to `FROM python:3.9` ?

Comment: @HansKilian backend container build fom img so did not work
sudo docker-compose build
db uses an image, skipping
backend uses an image, skipping
nginx uses an image, skipping

Comment: @CodeWizard
with python:3.9 no change

Comment: FWIW: The error message `exec format error` generally means "you're trying to run a binary that was compiled for a different architecture than the one on which you're running", but that doesn't make sense in this context. It doesn't have anything to do with whether gunicorn is installed or not, or what version of Python you're using. I'm not able to reproduce this behavior, so not sure what's actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if the image was built on ARM architecture (or Windows) and pulled to a regular Linux server. Build the image directly on the server.